# Upgrading bathtub?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I need to replace my current tub in the guest bathroom. It's an old fiberglass tub that's 32"x60"x75". Can I replace this with a 36"x60" tub? There's room in the alcove, I'm just wondering if I'll need to move the drain at all?

Comment: Do you have access from beneath?

Comment: Yes and no. I have access from behind the wet wall through the closet. This enabled me to measure from the stud to the drain pipe but most of the tubs I've looked at don't list that measurement.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you'll have to move it about 2 inches sideways, and potentially also some distance lengthwise, but that would depend on where it is in the current tub and where it is on the proposed replacement tub, which are things you should establish by measuring one with great care, and looking at the documentation of the other with great care.

Be sure to check that you can actually get it through the house to the bathroom. It seems to be rather common to install the tub and then frame up walls and doorways that mean you won't ever get it out in one piece, and therefore can't get a replacement the same size, much less larger, in; at least not in one piece.

Comment: Good point to bring up about getting the old tub out and new tub in.

Comment: I have been looking at tub and wall combos because of this. The doors will not allow a new three wall one piece to fit through. I'll have to cut up the old one to get it out. Had to do that to the one in the master bedroom for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

General answer: Yes you can replace it. You might have to modify the wall, cut/remove tile or drywall so the tub can fit in the space. As far as the drain is concerned, since the new tub will be wider and if up against the same wall, you'll have to change the drain if it's centered in the existing tub. If you can position the tub further into the existing wall so the existing drain lines up with the new tub drain, the changed could be minor.

To get a better answer, you'd need to post pictures of the existing drain and new tub. Unfortunately, the old tub would probably have to be removed before you'll really know what you're up against.

Comment: I know I'll be cutting out some drywall just to get the old tub out. It'll have to be cut up to be removed as it's a single piece.